# SQL comparison with expected result

Tags: sql

I want to compare my SQl result with expected result and display it as true or false depending if both the results  match or not

Expected result                 Actual Result(Pass/Fail)      result
today's date                            today's date             Pass

Comment: edit the question add some sample data & result with tag DBMS Product.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's no very clear what you want to do. If you are using a library or framework to integrate with your program, all  you have to do is retrieve the result from the DB and compare using boolean operations like `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, etc. Using this compare in a structure like an `if` `else` you can just `print` the result.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
with expected_results (id, col1, col2) as (
  values (1, 'some', 'thing'), 
         (2, 'another', 'value')
), actual_result (id, col2, col2) as (
  select id, col1, col2
  from your_table
    from .... --<< add your joins
  where .... --<< add your conditions
), diff (id, col1, col2) as (
  select *
  from expected_result
  except
  select *
  from actual_result

  union all 

  select *
  from actual_result
  except
  select *
  from expected_result
) 
select count(*) > 0 as "Result is correct"
from diff;
```

The first CTE builds up the result you expected, the second CTE runs your actual query. The CTE named `diff` calculates if there are any rows present in expected_result that are not in actual_result and combines that with the rows that are in actual_result but not in expected_result. If that set is empty, the actual and expected results are the same.

The example assumes that `id` is a unique identifier for a row in the expected result.

---

With Postgres you could simplify the detection of the differences using:

```
select count(*)
from actual_result ar 
  full outer join expected_result er on er.id = ar.id
where ar is distinct from er;
```

Comparing records like that is however not part of ANSI standard SQL.